# Should I use FULLTEXT index for varchar?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

If I have a structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sheet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `html` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `html` (`html`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and I need to do full text search queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms`
WHERE MATCH ( title, html) AGAINST ('+psoriasis +categorizacion' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Should I add a FULLTEXT index for `title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you should modify/replace your existing index so that it covers both columns (if you use `WHERE MATCH(title, html)...`, as opposed to `` `WHERE MATCH(title)... AND MATCH(html)... ``):

```sql
CREATE TABLE sheet (
    ...
    FULLTEXT KEY title_html (title, html)
    ...
)
```